# Update Class Based Off of Neighbor Class ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This probably has an answer somewhere, but I am having difficulty formulating a question.  I have a situation that hopefully someone can answer quickly.

```
<a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="span-1" id="unique_id1">content 1</span>
    <span class="span-2">content 2</span>
</a>
```

This is an simplified example of code I am using for a button (widget) for a website.  I need to be able to edit the inner HTML of the second `span` tag.  The problem is this code is implemented more than once, so I cannot use the class to change the text; I have to use the ID of the first span to make sure I only update the link I want to update.

I would like to do this using jQuery, but I can't seem to find a good place to start.  Essentially, it can be broken down to:

```
// where a link contains the ID of the span I need
    // update the HTML of the second span like:
    $("span.span-2").html("UPDATED");
```

Regards.

Comment: So your question is you know what `unique_id` will be and you want to update the span next to it?

Comment: I don't understand you, I entered in Goog: `jquery target next element` and there's the answer... Or is there something else I did not figure out from your question?

Comment: @zerkms seems to have nailed it for me. Essentially though, yes, that is what I needed to do.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was coming at the question/problem from a different angle and was making it more difficult then it needed to be. It's the end of the day and I'm tired. Hopefully you guys understand.

Comment: @burmat oh we do! We're every day in that condition! `°L°` `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#unique_id1').next('span')
```

?

Comment: I should have assumed it was something this simple (still learning jQuery, slowly but surely). I'm going to have to do work trying to get more information, but this should work fine. Thank you very much.